# How can I combine multiple lines of string into one line in Python with a space to separate them?

Tags: python, string, line

I have the following string:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

i want them to be like this:

```
text1 text2 text3 text4 text5
```

Can i do this using python?

Comment: Please show your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
s.replace("\n", " ")
```